# Subscribe to changes in array outside react

Tags: reactjs

I have a legacy web application that fetches data about beverages and stores it. I am now modernizing the presentation by building React components on top of the legacy app.

I want my React component to update when a new item is fetched from the server and pushed to an array of the legacy application storage.
Can this be done without the need for an external signaling framework?
This is basically what I want:

```
// Legacy web app 
MyLegacyApp.Storage.Beverages = [item1, item2...];


// React component
export default class BeveragesView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            beverages: MyLegacyApp.Storage.Beverages // And also track any changes to this
        };
    }
    // ... rest of the component
}
```

Usually this would be done automatically by keeping everything in React state and update that. It is way too much work to move the fetching and storage to React so I am restricted to keep the storage in the legacy application.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is whether you can call an api in your reactjs application without setting up a server or using redux, then the answer is 'yes'. A short and explanatory description can be found [here](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/)